# Late answer and first post queues contain the same entry.

Tags: discussion, review

When I reviewed last time, I got the same entry in both the "Late answer" and "First Post" review queues. Is it a bug or a known issue? And sometimes already flagged entries also appeared in the first post section. When flag it again I get the message, "You have already flagged it". Any ideas, improvements?

Comment: Known issue; some posts are both a first post *and* a late answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: So, how they taken for the calculation?

Comment: What do you mean? If you click "I'm Done" the second time, it is still recorded as a review.